# Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1 on AWS-EMR but works on local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a simple mapreduce code just to read using mapper.py, taking the output of mapper.py and reading by reducer.py. This code works on local computer but when I tried on aws-emr, it gives the following error -

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
```

Here is the input.txt, mapper.py and reducer.py

### input.txt

```
scott,haris
jenifer,smith
ted,brandy
amanda,woods
bob,wilton
damn,halloween
```

### mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    x = line.strip()
    first,last = x.split(",")
    print '%s\t%s' % (first, last)
```

### reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    x = line.strip()
    key, value = x.split('\t')
    print '%s\t%s' % (key, value)
```

I am using the following command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-streaming.jar -files s3://test/mapper.py,s3://test/reducer.py -mapper "python mapper.py" -reducer "python reducer.py" -input s3://test/input.txt -output s3://test/output
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have problem with python `reducer` / `mapper` script, can you check two things below

1.Are your `Mapper` and `Reducer` scripts executable(make sure you are pointing to right env with , like try `#!/usr/bin/python` ) and have right permissions?

2.Your Python program is right, for example if server is running python3, you need to have brackets for `print()` or any other issue with the script.

Try to execute python normally in emr with bash and see if it works

Comment: I checked mapper.py and reducer.py. Both are executable (chmod a+x mapper.py, chmod a+x reducer.py). It works locally using-  cat input.txt | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py.  But does not work on aws emr using hadoop-streaming.